# How Debug This error? "Method Not Allowed (POST)"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

> Hello. My friends, when I complete the form on the HTML side and send
> it to the Django side for validation. I get "Django Method Not Allowed
> (POST)" error.
>
> Description of the error: the get method works and sends the form to
> HTML, but the post method does not work properly, and when the button
> on the HTML side is clicked, the browser page freezes, and this
> "Method Not Allowed (POST):" occurs in the Django terminal.

> home.urls

```
urlpatterns = [path('',views.HomePageView.as_view(),name='home')]
```

> this is main urls

```
urlpatterns = [
                path('', include('home.urls')),
                path('contact-us/', include('contact.urls')),
                path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
                path('account/', include('account.urls')),
                path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
            ]
    
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this is urls 'contact app'

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('send-ticket/',views.ContactView.as_view(),name='contact')
    ]
```

> this is form html side

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'contact' %}" name="contact" >
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        {{ forms.name.label_tag }}
                                        {{ forms.name }}
                                        {{ forms.name.errors }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        {{ forms.surname.label_tag}}
                                        {{ forms.surname}}
                                        {{ forms.surname.errors }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        {{ forms.email.label_tag }}
                                        {{ forms.email }}
                                        {{ forms.email.errors }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        {{ forms.subject.label_tag}}
                                        {{ forms.subject }}
                                        {{ forms.subject.errors }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        {{ forms.text.label_tag }}
                                        {{ forms.text }}
                                        {{ forms.text.errors }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
```

---

Send Message
Now

> this is  my model

```
   class ContactUs(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, )
        surname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, )
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, null=True, )
        subject = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, )
        text = models.TextField(null=True, )
```

> this is my form

```
    class ContactModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ContactUs
            fields = \['name', 'email', 'surname', 'subject', 'text'\]
            widgets = {
           'name': forms.TextInput(),
           'surname': forms.TextInput(),
           'email': forms.EmailInput(),
           'subject': forms.TextInput(),
           'text': forms.Textarea(),}
```

> This my view,this is not a complete view, it is just for testing

```
 class ContactView(View):

   def get(self, request):
      form = ContactModelForm()
      return render(request, 'contact/contact_us.html', {'forms': form})

   def post(self, request):
       form = ContactModelForm(request.POST)``
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect('home')

       return render(request, 'contact/contact_us.html',{'forms':form'})
```

Comment: Share the relevant template and urls file as well.

Comment: Looks like your `post` method is defined *outside* the view.

Comment: first of all  thank you guys for ansewrs and attention.I tried all the baseview classes I knew. I checked the HTML form many times, Django form, Django model, URLS main and URLS app, Settings of the whole project. I even deleted my database and rebuilt it again, but the error was not fixed.

Comment: Can you include thee whole line of the error.

Comment: Can you also share the `home.urls`?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your `post` method is defined *outside* the view, but you are writing way too much boilerplate code. What you here construct is a [**`CreateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), you can use:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


class ContactView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'contact/contact_us.html'
    form_class = ContactModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Furthermore, in your template, you made an error for the `surname` field:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    {{ forms.surname.label_tag }}
    {{ forms.surname }}
    {{ forms.surname.errors }}
</div>
```

Comment: i tried before but doesn't work

Comment: @Mohammad: you also made an error in the template.

Comment: The error still persists.

Comment: @Mohammad: is this the only `path`? Can you edit the question with *all* `urls.py`?

Comment: I only defined this one path in the URL of this app. This error occurs wherever I have a form.

Comment: I think the problem is related to routing, but I don't know where it is. Maybe someone more experienced will understand